# javascript removechild

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete a hidden element. I have tried the following codes but it always returns the parent as undefined.

attempt one

```
var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time");
timeLeft.document.removeChild(timeLeft);
```

attempt two

```
var timeLeftBody, timeLeft;
timeLeftBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
timeLeft = document.getElementById("time");
timeLeft.timeLeftBody.removeChild(timeLeft);
```

Comment: Could you please show the markup?

Comment: In both of your snippets of code, the last line begins with `timeleft.` for no obvious reason. Is that a transcription error here or is it really part of what you're doing, and if so why? Also, I agree with `kojiro`; you should show us what your document actually contains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`removeChild()` only works on an element that directly contains the child -- `document.removeChild(hdr)` won't work unless the document directly contains the `time` element (which is impossible, unless `time` is the `html` node).

Try:

```
var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time");
timeLeft.parentNode.removeChild(timeLeft);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
timeLeft.timeLeftBody.removeChild(timeLeft);
```

...to this:

```
timeLeftBody.removeChild(timeLeft);
```

Basically, you were chaining things together unneccesarily. You want to follow this basic format:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('idOfParentNode');
var child = document.getElementById('idOfNodeToRemoveFromParent');
parent.removeChild(child);
```